# Get rid of line breaks in SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

In SSMS, I can edit a view via `right click` > `script view as` > `create/alter/etc.` This brings up a window like this

```
USE [DataBaseName]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[ViewName]    Script Date: 02/9/2015 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER view [dbo].[ViewName] as

--Script goes here
--Script goes here

GO
```

Each time I open the view, SSMS adds a line break between the script and the text around it, until it eventually looks like

```
USE [DataBaseName]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[ViewName]    Script Date: 02/9/2015 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO





ALTER view [dbo].[ViewName] as

--Script goes here
--Script goes here





GO
```

How do I disable this? While tolerable, it's a bit irritating and I'd rather not have to spend time deleting line breaks. I found [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982168/extra-line-while-opening-script-in-sql-server-2012?rq=1) but it didn't have any answers.

Comment: Use a SQL Formatter?

Comment: @FutbolFan I'd rather not use third-party tools for this. At that point, manually deleting the spaces would still be faster. Are there really no settings where this can be adjusted?

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe there is, I never had the need to change it though.